# how to use sscanf with speficied length

Tags: c++

I want to convert an array of unsigned char to integer using sscanf, but convert only 3 characters

```
unsigned char buffer[] = "FF34567A9";
sscanf((const char *)buffer, "%x %x %x", &x, &y, &z);
```

result expected for x  = FF3, y = 456 z = 7A9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general , you can do this in loop for multiple values like this

```
int arr[MAXN];
unsigned char* tmp = buffer;
for ( int i = 0; sscanf((const char*)tmp, "%3x", &arr[i]); ++i, tmp += 3 );
```

Comment: it works but it display always unsigned value in `arr` , even by declaring arr `unsigned int arr` for example when I cout FFFF ,it should display -1

Comment: FFFF is indeed a positive number , as integers are 32-bit in size.

Answer (score 0):

GIven that you don't seems to know the type of your variable yourself (eg. declaring a constant without const, at least before the edit, just to cast it later to const, and the unsigned thing) I'm recommending `std::string`:

```
std::string s = "123456789";
s = s.substr(0, 3);
int x = std::stoi(s);
```

About your edit:

```
std::string s = "123456789";
int x = std::stoi(s.substr(0, 3));
int y = std::stoi(s.substr(3, 3));
int z = std::stoi(s.substr(6, 3));
```